# Returning empty object in Laravel resource instead of null

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js

I do have a resource (DeviceResource) in my Laravel API which contains another resource (SimcardResource). There is a OnetoOne relationship between those resources but sometimes a device has no associated simcard.
If this is the case my DeviceResource returns for the simcard null instead of an empty json object.
I do need an empty json object because I present information called from my API in my Vue frontend by accessing an object e.g. like device.simcard.phone_number

My DeviceResource class looks like this:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->resource->id,
            'model' => $this->resource->model,
            'device_name' => $this->resource->device_name,
            'operating_system' => $this->resource->operating_system,
            'os_version' => $this->resource->os_version,
            'emei' => $this->resource->emei,
            'device_password' => $this->resource->device_password,
            'purchase_date' => $this->resource->purchase_date,
            'associated_worker' => $this->resource->associated_worker,
            'remarks' => $this->resource->remarks,
            'device_status_id' => $this->resource->device_status_id,
            // 'simcard' => $this->resource->simcard ?: (object)[],
            'simcard' => SimcardResource::make($this->whenLoaded('simcard'))  ?: (object)[],
        ];
    }
```

The commented section:

```
'simcard' => $this->resource->simcard ?: (object)[]
```

Works perfectly but returns all fields from my simcard table but I only need fields defined in my SimcardResource class so I tried the following:

```
'simcard' => SimcardResource::make($this->whenLoaded('simcard'))  ?: (object)[]
```

But it still returns null instead of an empty json object.

Comment: i think its supposed to be ```?? (object)[];``` not ```?:```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Laravel resource default behaviour that if you do not have any data than resource will also return you the null resource object. You have to manage it yourself in other way like by defining each parameter has null value that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay maybe its not the best solution but my DeviceResource class now looks like this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    if (is_null($this->resource->simcard)) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->resource->id,
            'model' => $this->resource->model,
            'device_name' => $this->resource->device_name,
            'operating_system' => $this->resource->operating_system,
            'os_version' => $this->resource->os_version,
            'emei' => $this->resource->emei,
            'device_password' => $this->resource->device_password,
            'purchase_date' => $this->resource->purchase_date,
            'associated_worker' => $this->resource->associated_worker,
            'remarks' => $this->resource->remarks,
            'device_status_id' => $this->resource->device_status_id,
            'simcard' => (object) [],
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            'id' => $this->resource->id,
            'model' => $this->resource->model,
            'device_name' => $this->resource->device_name,
            'operating_system' => $this->resource->operating_system,
            'os_version' => $this->resource->os_version,
            'emei' => $this->resource->emei,
            'device_password' => $this->resource->device_password,
            'purchase_date' => $this->resource->purchase_date,
            'associated_worker' => $this->resource->associated_worker,
            'remarks' => $this->resource->remarks,
            'device_status_id' => $this->resource->device_status_id,
            // 'simcard' => $this->resource->simcard ?: (object)[],
            'simcard' => SimcardResource::make($this->whenLoaded('simcard')),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes @djwest this is what i am saying in my answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel introduce best ways,for example [whenLoaded](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships),but try this

```
... ?? json_encode(new stdClass)
```

Comment: Yea this does not work